# Line break in TeX

Tags: tex-core

I'm using XeTeX and I want to specify a line break. There seem to be several ways to do this for LaTeX, but I have not found any for TeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you want to break a line in plain TeX (my answer assumes that)? If not, then please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

To break a line in plain TeX you could issue `\break` (or more user-friendly `\hfil\break`; if you use justified paragraphs this will not lead to "ugly line filling") at the point you want TeX to break.

However you should not break too many lines manually. Most times you want to do a paragraph break, because it is meant to separate different parts of the text.